# UITableView content that's not in a cell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was handed a code base for a screen with a UITableView with a bunch of sections. One thing I have to do is add a Segmented Control to switch some of the sections on and off, depending on the user's province.

I'd like to put the segmented control along the top of the screen, right under an existing header image. However, I'm at a loss as to how they got the image there in the first place. It seems to be "inside" the table view, but when I try to place my control there it rejects the drag.

Notice the view hierarchy in the following image. I've tried dragging into this part of the screen as well as the storyboard, but nothing seems to let me put it there.

I'm sure this is *extremely* simply, but anyone know the trick?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried dragging a segmented control to that position, and you're right, Xcode wouldn't let me do it. However, you *can* drag a UIImageView or a UIView to that position. So the solution is to first drag a `UIView` there, and then drag the segmented control into the `UIView`.

Comment: Ahhh, perhaps the problem is that you can only have one of them, and it has to be there? I can't see anything in the docs about that, but maybe?